# Is there a shortcut for Disjunction.fold(identity, identity)?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a scalaz `Disjunction` with the same types like `Disjunction[String, String]` and I just want to get the value, whatever it is. I therefore used `myDisjunction.fold(indentity, identity)` but I wonder, is there a shortcut like `myDisjunction.safeGetBecauseTypesAreEqual()`?

Comment: I think you want [`merge`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L324)?

Comment: That's it, I'm blind. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `merge`:

```
val s: String = myDisjunction.merge()
```